# Grails: Is there a way to retrieve _idx property of an Object in a List?

Tags: list, grails

I have an association like this

```
class Parent 
List children

static hasMany =[children:Child]
```

I need to be able to know the **order** of a Child object when I look at it outside of Parent context. So that I can tell if it is a 1st child, second child, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean with '*outside of Parent context*'? To get index of a object in a list - you need to load it before. If you want to get index without loading Parent, then you have to use an raw SQL for this, but i'm not sure that it will be faster than loading Parent, because it's the same logic, except making mapping resultset to a model.

Btw, to get this index when you have `Parent` instance, you have to use:

```
int idx = parent.children.indexOf(child)
```

And don't forget to implement `.equals` of your `Child` domain.

Comment: I see your point. I was hoping there was a groovy way of getting to the idx property. I know that the framework itself uses that property to index the list (how do I know? try changing the idx in the database table - grails blows up :) )